# How to get editable datagridview cell value to textbox

Tags: c#

I have two `textbox` named *AmtPaid* and *AmtBalance* and below a `datagridview` with four columns and the 3rd column is *AmtPaid* . Default value for *AmtPaid*  `textbox` is set to 0.`Datagridview` is editable. so as soon as i reached the 3rd column and type some values in that cell that entered value must fill the the above *AmtPaid* `textbox`.
How can i do it? Please help.

Comment: If this is a web page (based on the asp.net tag), you will need to use client side scripting to update web page controls without posting back to the server. Are you familiar with jQuery? It comes bundled with a lot of asp.net solutions templates. You should also provide some code with your question to help us understand the situation.

Comment: no, this is windows form application

Comment: remove asp.net tag then.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the link form MSDN site. I think the question in this link matches your requirement.

[DataGridView text changed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a56ac5c1-e71f-4a12-bbfa-ab8fc7b36f1c/datagridview-text-changed?forum=winformsdatacontrols)

Answer (score 0):

Use DataGridView Cell Value Changed Event (something like)

inside the Event you can access value of datagridview cell value:

```
textBox1.Text=dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value.ToString();
```

Like this